# Background clip text with translateY position

Tags: css

I'm having an issue while testing background text clipping.
I want to vertical center the div, that has a variable height. So i used TranslateY. The problem is that the background clip image also moves while it should.

I got a small demo over here:
http://jsfiddle.net/NickNoordijk/b3kehddk/2/

Remove the rule, to set the TEST text at the correct position.

```
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Does anyone has a solution for me ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The image is the background of the div with the text. You might want to try placing the image as the background of a div containing the div with the text.

Comment: Good one, but it still isn't working. The translateY just wont work with the clipped background. I used flexbox to get the content to it's center and that worked :) keep the flexbox support in mind when you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is what you want.

Alternate way to center text:

horizontal: set left and right to 0px, margin to auto.
vertical: set top and bottom to 0px. set height to 1em

```css
/* Main styles */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);

.box-with-text {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/codrops-playground/assets/images/posts/23145/image1.jpg);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

/* Other styles */
body {
  background-image: url(http://tympanus.net/codrops-playground/assets/images/posts/23145/image1.jpg);
    
   
    
  color: #FFF;
}

.box-with-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 1em;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 26vmax/.85 Open Sans, Impact;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-with-text">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but it's not the solution. I need the full background + text background image in the same position despite the window size.